# Boost errors when compiling xbt on Debian

Tags: debian, boost

I'm trying to compile xbt on a Debian machine, but `boost/make_shared.hpp` is not found.

```
In file included from ./stdafx.h:32,
                 from ../misc/bvalue.cpp:1:
../misc/xbt/virtual_binary.h:5:33: error: boost/make_shared.hpp: No such file or directory
../misc/bvalue.cpp: In member function 'Cvirtual_binary Cbvalue::read() const':
../misc/bvalue.cpp:308: error: 'BOOST_VERIFY' was not declared in this scope
```

`apt-cache show libboost-dev` says the following, if it helps:

```
Package: libboost-dev
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 28156
Maintainer: Debian Boost Team <pkg-boost-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: boost
Version: 1.34.1-14
```

How can I update boost to the latest version on Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Debian are you running? libboost-dev is at 1.34.1-14 in Lenny (aka oldstable).

I'm not sure which version of the library you need for xbt since I couldn't find the build requirements for it anywhere but 1.42.0.1 is available in Squeeze. Have you considered upgrading to Squeeze?